# How to change texts in Fragments?

Tags: android-fragments, nullpointerexception, fragment, settext, updateview

I want to change texts in fragments, but I keep getting error like this

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.widget.TextView com.javahelp.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding.Aboutus' on a null object reference in method 'android.view.View com.javahelp.frontend.fragments.HomeFragment.onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle)'
```

`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    binding.Aboutus.setText("Changed");
    return v;
}
```

`

The one below is the mainpage where I am switching fragments
`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityFgBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());
    replaceFragment(new HomeFragment());

    binding.bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(item ->{
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.home:
                replaceFragment(new HomeFragment());
                break;
            case R.id.account:
                replaceFragment(new AccountFragment());
                break;
            case R.id.search:
                replaceFragment(new SearchFragment());
                break;
        }
        return true;
    });
}
```

`

I was expecting the word "About Us" in home fragment would change to "Changed". I am trying to see if setText is working, but it is not. I looked for possible solutions, but they are not working.So I am not sure how to solve this. Appreciate some help and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

you can not set text in **onCreateView** method, put this line into **onViewCreated** method